# Returning values if it is greater than and less than to a specific value using UDF

Tags: excel, excel-udf, vba

I am currently working on a UDF which returns and concatenates the headers if it is greater than and less than to a specific value. I’m not really good in Excel-Vba and what I got so far is this pathetic code which I couldn’t understand anymore. I would truly appreciate it if someone could help. Here's what i got so far:

```
Public Function greaterLessValue(Rng As Range, Rng2 As Range, greater, less)

Dim rngArr() As Variant
rngArr = Rng.value

For i = 1 To UBound(rngArr, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(rngArr, 2)
        If rngArr(i, j) = xVal Then
            For k = 1 To UBound(rngArr, 2)
                If rngArr(i, k) = Yval Then countRowAsso = countRowAsso + 1
            Next k
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Function
```

If the value is greater than or equal to 5 and less than and equal to 10 it should return the same example bellow which concatenates the Header containing the specific value in the same column:

[image]

Comment: This code has *absolutely nothing* to do with your objective. :o

Comment: yeah sorry about that but you nailed it though...

Comment: Well you have now three excellent and different solutions, that's a record :)

Comment: Given that the only difference between the code you posted and some code written by @ScottCraner is the function name `MyCount` being changed to `greaterLessValue` (and then incorrectly referred to as `countRowAsso` in the code), I think it is extremely rude to describe the code as "pathetic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A.S.H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926357/a-s-h) makes a good point on confirming that the ranges hold the same number of elements/values/cells. I've used a different approach.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function greaterLessValue(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, _
                                 greater As Double, lesser As Double)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rngArr1 As Variant, rngArr2 As Variant

    rngArr1 = rng1.Value2
    rngArr2 = rng2.Value2
    greaterLessValue = ""

    'use for showing array extents
    'delete or comment out when function works
    Debug.Print LBound(rngArr1, 1) & " to " & UBound(rngArr1, 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(rngArr1, 2) & " to " & UBound(rngArr1, 2)

    'used to ensure that the ranges hold the same number of columns
    'only affects the 2nd rank when used with Preserve
    ReDim Preserve rngArr2(LBound(rngArr1, 1) To UBound(rngArr1, 1), _
                            LBound(rngArr1, 2) To UBound(rngArr1, 2))

    For i = LBound(rngArr1, 1) To UBound(rngArr1, 1)
        For j = LBound(rngArr1, 2) To UBound(rngArr1, 2)
            If IsNumeric(rngArr2(i, j)) Then
                If rngArr2(i, j) >= greater And rngArr2(i, j) <= lesser Then
                    greaterLessValue = greaterLessValue & _
                                       IIf(CBool(Len(greaterLessValue)), ", ", vbNullString) & _
                                       rngArr1(i, j)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Function
```

Syntax as per the following image:

[image]

Comment: you are a genius sir thank you ill rate every sing answers u made in the past.. im so grateful i thought this wasn't possible

Comment: Nino, please don't. That counts as voter fraud and will just be repealed.

Comment: Where you been these last 3 months?  I have made a lot of mistakes that you usually caught for me. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner - moved to a farm and went native. Had to put in a third wireless extender to get internet access.

Comment: We all missed you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this UDF:

```
Public Function greaterLess(values As Range, header As Range, a, b) As String
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In values
        If cel.value >= a And cel.value <= b Then greaterLess  = _ 
          greaterLess & header.Cells(1, cel.Column - values.Column + 1) & ", "
    Next
End Function
```

**Usage**

Enter the following formula in Cell `N2` :

```
=greaterLess(B2:M2, B$1:M$1, 5, 10)
```

Then copy `N2`, select `N3:N7` and paste.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Office 365 Excel you can do this with an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF((B2:M2>=5)*(B2:M2<=10),B$1:M$1,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode.  IF done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel then you can use this UDF that will mimic the function.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

The formula is the same and still entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.